# Gridview Error Data Contains No Rows when Used with Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have this Linq statement that filters transactions. It works fine when it filters but I get an error in dt.AsEnumerable() when there is nothing being returned.

The error is Data contains no row. Anybody know how to handle when there is nothing returned?

```
      newDataTable = dt.AsEnumerable()
                    .Where(r => !ListLinkedIds.Contains(r.Field<int>("LinkedTicketId")))
                    .CopyToDataTable();  

      gvMain.DataSource = newDataTable;
      gvMain.DataBind();
```

Comment: Check IEnumerable result before calling .CopyToDataTable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `CopyToDataTable` if the input sequence is empty. So you need to check that first:

```
var newDataTable = dt.Clone();  // an empty table with the same schema
var ticketRows = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(r => !ListLinkedIds.Contains(r.Field<int>("LinkedTicketId")));
if(ticketRows.Any())
    newDataTable = ticketRows.CopyToDataTable();
```

Possible exceptions with [`CopytoDataTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396189.aspx)

- ArgumentNullException
  The source IEnumerable sequence is null and a new table cannot be created.
- InvalidOperationException

  - A DataRow in the source sequence has a state of Deleted.
  - **The source sequence does not contain any DataRow objects.**
  - A DataRow in the source sequence is null.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your `DataTable` has any rows before calling `AsEnumerable()`

```
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
      newDataTable = dt.AsEnumerable()
                    .Where(r => !ListLinkedIds.Contains(r.Field<int>("LinkedTicketId")))
                    .CopyToDataTable();  

      gvMain.DataSource = newDataTable;
      gvMain.DataBind();
    }
    else {
    //error
    }
```

Comment: The problem is not the table but the `Where`.